# How to interpret $\nabla_x (f(u(x)))$? Is $\nabla_x (f(u(x)))= (\nabla f) (u(x)) \nabla u$ true?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

Let $u:\mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb C$ be a function and $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $f(z)=|z|^{\frac{4}{n-2}}z.$ Thus, composition of $f$ and $u$ is: $f(u)= |u|^{\frac{4}{n-2}}u.$

> My Question is: How should I interpret  $\nabla_x (f(u(x)))$? Is  $\nabla_x (f(u(x)))= (\nabla f) (u(x)) \nabla u$ true?

[Is this a standard notaions? My understnding for the gradient is: if $g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb C$ nice function then $\nabla g (x) = (\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_n}), x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n$. Or am I missing something here?  But I do not knwo what is means $\nabla_x g$, which was used by the autors in the remark mentioned below]

**Motivation:** I have been trying to figure out  [Remark 2.3 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610266v1.pdf) See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901924/let-fu-u-frac4n-2u-then-partial-z-fu-leq-c-u-frac4/1902059#1902059)

Answer (score 1):

When you are starting with this work, it is best to look at the components.  Let $x= (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. $\nabla_x(f(u(x)))$ is an $n-$component vector.  The first component of $\nabla_x(f(u(x)))$ is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=\frac{d f}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}$$
The first derivative in this chain rule expression is not a partial derivative, since $f$ is a function of a scalar $u$ (so you won't have anything that looks like $\nabla f$).  Since the other components will be similar, you obtain
$$\nabla_x(f(u(x)))=(\frac{d f}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},\frac{d f}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2},...,\frac{d f}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n})$$ 
$$=\frac{df}{du} \nabla u$$

Comment: Thanks.  I guess u  mean to say there is nothing like $\nabla f$? But then why the authors have repeatedly used $\nabla_{x} (f(u(x)))=  (\nabla f) (u(x)) \nabla u$ ?

Comment: And  $u:\mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb C$

Comment: To your first comment, this is the more general case when $f$ is multivariate.  However, the notation here is sloppy, since it has a vector times a vector, without explaining what that multiplication looks like.

Comment: To your second, I had a typo: I meant you won't have anything like $\nabla f$.

Answer (score -1):

Try the chain rule for multivariate calculus: https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/

Comment: JEM: Thanks.  I am unable to see, how does it help here. Would you please tell bit further?

Comment: I mean that you should use the gradient function as you know, just using the chain rule for each of the derivatives, as you have composed functions involved in your derivative, and as your gradient has the index $x$, means that the gradient should be done respect to that variable.