# What is a Chain rule for gradient?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defirrentiable funtion then we know that the composition funtion $h=g\circ f$ is diffentiable and $$\frac{d}{dx} h(x)= h'(x)= f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) $$ (Here $\cdot $ denotes the real number multiplication)

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb C$ and $g:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C.$ Consider composition function $h:\mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb C$ as $h(x)= g\circ f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb R^n.$

> My Question: (1) What is the anologe of the above formula in higher dimension? 
>    (2) What is a gradient of $h= g\circ f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb C$? In other words, what is, keeping  the above formula in mind,  $\nabla h (x)$, ($x\in \mathbb R^n$)? Can we say $\nabla h(x)= \nabla g (f(x)) \cdot \nabla u (x)$ and now what is a meaning of $\cdot $ here?

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to view $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$ unless you assume analyticity. Looking at it this way, $g$ and $f$ both have Jacobian matrices $J_f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $J_g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and you have $J_{g \circ f}(x)=J_g(f(x)) J_f(x)$ (where concatenation denotes matrix multiplication or equivalently composition of linear maps). If in fact $g$ is a holomorphic function then $J_g$ is isomorphic to the complex-valued function $g'$ by the isomorphism $a+bi \sim \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: :Thanks: Can I think of $\nabla h(x)= \partial_{z}g(f(x)) \nabla f(x) $ (For a fix $x\in \mathbb R^n$, $f(x)\in \mathbb C$ )?

Comment: Is that assuming that $g$ is holomorphic? Otherwise that is a bad way to think about it. (Really just in general that's kind of a bad way to think about it; in my experience you're either doing complex analysis or you're not.)

Comment: I am trying to figure out the [Remark 2.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610266v1.pdf)

Comment: See [also](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901924/let-fu-u-frac4n-2u-then-partial-z-fu-leq-c-u-frac4)

Comment: Well, you can do all of that sticking with this framework by just writing the Jacobians in the coordinate system $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks: But would please explain bit further? Are you saying $\nabla h(x) = \partial_z g(f(x)) \nabla f(x)$ is true by this changing coordinate system?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by $\nabla f$. It's not immediately obvious to me (without actually doing some coordinate calculations) that $J_f$ can be represented as a vector of complex numbers. As for $J_g$, in general you *cannot* represent $J_g$ as $(\partial_z g)$. You necessarily need a $\partial_{\overline{z}}$ component in there as well. Assuming analyticity this component vanishes, however.